# Session expires when going to root website

Tags: java, session, tomcat8

After an admin has logged in, he can go to the website where he will be able to now see buttons that wasn't accessable before.
This works fine as long as the admin accesses the website via
www.example.com/

but if it is done via

www.example.com

Both use the same servlet.

It seems the Session object is lost, and the admin is logged out.

I don't recieve any erros, and I'm completely lost as to what can be causing this. If I need to provide anything more, just request it :)

Answer (score 0):

you should get session in servlet before login process.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
datatype variable = session.getAttribute("varibleName you set before");
```

if session was not exist then read request and login admin and if it existed do nothing.

Comment: The problem is not with getting the session, as I mentioned this works perfectly when adding a / to the url, but not without.
And this is the same servlet it gets directed to.

Comment: have you introduce your servlet  and your welcome page in web.xml?

Comment: Yes i have :) It works fine, I get no errors, but the session object seems no be lost